# how to run an exe file inside a folder using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am having a folder location like

`C:\Users\Pathfinder\contribute\test`

which consists of `postgresql-9.0.13-1-windows.exe` file.

I have a batch file test.bat and I want to run it using a script.

I'm new to batch scripting so what i tried is :-

```
CD \Users\Pathfinder\contribute\test
postgresql-9.0.13-1-windows.exe postgresql-9.0.13-1-windows.exe --mode unattended
```

but its not working.

do i have try like this

```
CD \Users\Pathfinder\contribute\test
run postgresql-9.0.13-1-windows.exe postgresql-9.0.13-1-windows.exe --mode unattended
```

or

```
CD \Users\Pathfinder\contribute\test
start postgresql-9.0.13-1-windows.exe postgresql-9.0.13-1-windows.exe --mode unattended
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper quote your paths

```
"C:\Users\Pathfinder\contribute\test\postgresql-9.0.13-1-windows.exe" --mode unattended
```

so system understands what is your path to executable and what are the arguments.

Comment: thanx
What if folder name is "Demo start"?
C:\Users\Demo start\contribute\test
Do i have to give path like
C:\Users\'Demo start'\contribute\test  ?

Comment: You may keep all path inside quotes: `"C:\Users\Demo start\contribute\test\..."` AFAIK, quotes were introduced to handle spaces in file system names.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try directly *C:\path to Users\Users\Pathfinder\contribute\test\postgresql-9.0.13-1-windows.exe*?

Of course, replace C: with the drive letter if different

Comment: thanx for replying. i tried what you suggested but getting error  "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's because the editor cut out part of what I typed:

Try: C:\The path to your Users folder\Users\Pathfinder\contribute\test\postgresql-9.0.13-1-windows.exe

Comment: ya you are right but as what my question is ... i have to run this exe file with mode unattended i.e

postgresql-9.0.13-1-windows.exe --mode unattended

This whole thing i have to run.

Comment: thanx cristi ... i got the answer . i have to just append it only  :)